# Set css property without css transition

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I have an element for which I need to toggle the opacity.  Sometimes I want to transition the opacity, and sometimes I do not.  Is there an easy way to reset the property without the transition using JavaScript some of the time without turning the transition off?

Comment: why dont you just manage the opacity with js instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to reset the property without the transition using JavaScript some of the time without turning the transition off?

Not that I know of. A transition occurs when the property it is set on changes – how that change occurs, does not matter.

But there is an easy way *of* turning it off – apply the transition via a class, and then remove that class dynamically when you want to change the property value without transition.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, but thanks for confirming.